# Getting a functor as argument in C++11

Tags: c++, class, c++11, generics, functor

I want the following code to run:

```
class SignedSquareRoot {
public:
    int operator()(int val) {
        return val >= 0 ? sqrt(val) : -sqrt(-val);
    };
}
```

So I wrote the following in my class:

declaration:

```
    template<class Function>
    Matrix<T> apply(Function function);
```

implementation:

```
template<class T, class Function>
    Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::apply(Function function) {
        Matrix<T> out = *this;
        int size = this->size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            out.data[i] = function(out.data[i]);
        }
        return out;
    }
```

But I'm getting many error like:

> error: too many template parameters in template redeclaration
>       template
>
> note: previous template declaration is here
>       template

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Make it

```
template <typename T>
template <typename Function>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::apply(Function function) { ... }
```

You need two separate sets of template parameters, one for the class template and one for the member function template of that class.

Comment: But why two separate, what's the difference?

Comment: You have two templates in play, so two instances of `template` keyword. After all, you wrote `template` twice when you declared that function, too: `template <typename T> class Matrix { template <typename Function> Matrix apply(Function); };` The definition mirrors the declaration.